# GCP IoT stops processing messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

We have multiple devices (rpi2) connected to IoT core with our self-engineered "firmware" that uses Python and Paho-mqtt client. Our steps to reproduce error:

1. Log into Google Cloud
2. Set device to DEBUG logging level.
3. Attempt to send command using Google's IoT website (e.g., remote firmware update or just anything other)
4. Observe immediate error responses (two cases below) from the Google control panel.
5. Observe the logs on the device; no record of contact from GCP.

And the two cases are:

1. Message couldn’t be sent because the device is not connected
   This is true and not true, because we are seeing that our device gets disconnected from time to time without particular reason. We do have JWT token refreshing mechanism and it's working fine, but sometimes GCP just... disconnects device!
2. The command couldn't be sent because the device is not subscribed to the MQTT wildcard topic.
   This is not true, all devices are subscribed (but if they are not connected then maybe they are not subscribed...)

Here are the things that we already checked:
1. The JWT are refreshed 10 minutes faster than one hour (the expiry is set to 3600, but we refresh every 3000 seconds)
2. Explicitly set MQTTv311 as the protocol to speak in Python Paho-mqtt client
3. Implemented an on_log() handler.
4. Implemented PINGREQ as IoT core documentation stated.
5. Checked devices' internet connection and it's just fine.

Here are some logs:

1. From device:

```html
[2020-04-05 21:20:58,624] root - INFO - Trying to set date and time to: 2020-04-05 21:20:58.624278
[2020-04-05 21:20:59,239] root - INFO - Starting collecting device state
[2020-04-05 21:20:59,256] root - INFO - Connecting to the cloud
[2020-04-05 21:20:59,262] root - INFO - Device client_id is 'projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/registries/iot-registry/devices/XXX-000003'
[2020-04-05 21:20:59,549] root - INFO - Starting pusher service
[2020-04-05 21:21:00,050] root - INFO - on_connect: Connection Accepted.
[2020-04-05 21:21:00,051] root - INFO - Subscribing to /devices/XXX-000003/commands/#
[2020-04-05 21:22:04,827] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:20:59.549934, pusher sent: 469 messages, received confirmation for 469 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:23:07,426] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:22:04.828064, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:24:09,815] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:23:07.427720, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:25:12,036] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:24:09.816221, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:26:14,099] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:25:12.037507, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:27:16,052] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:26:14.100430, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:28:17,807] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:27:16.053253, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
[2020-04-05 21:29:19,416] root - INFO - Since 2020-04-05T21:28:17.808075, pusher sent: 6 messages, received confirmation for 6 messages, recorded 0 errors
```

2. From GCP:
   [GCP logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lowe5.png)

Comment: Hi Janek, just a quick question. Each of your Rpi devices are using own device identity, so they are registered as separated devices in IoT Core?

Comment: Hi Kornel, yes, each is registered as separate device in IoT with it's own device ID.

Comment: I recommend to open a support case to investigate further.